# Buck regulator thermals calculations

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, buck, temperature, power-dissipation

Schematic:
[image]

Specification:
Vin = 24V
Vout =5V
Iout max = 8A
Freq = 0.691 Mhz

Assumptions: Good layout and FETs mounted on 1-2 inch^2 of copper.

Calculations based on this doc: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3150.pdf?ts=1644834420223&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.it%252F

**High side Fet:**
Datasheet -> https://docs.rs-online.com/41b0/0900766b810c9618.pdf
Continuous loss:
[image]

Rdson = 13m

Normalised for Vgs and junction temp = 13m *1.3 = 16.9m

P cond = 8^2 *16.9m * (5/24) = **0.225W**

[image]

[image]

1/2 * 24 * 8 * 3.1n * 0.691M * ((8.5/6-2) + (6.8/2)) = **1.136W**

Total loss in high side = 1.136 + 0.225 = **1.36W**

[image]

Total temp rise = 1.36*40 = **54.44C**

**Low side FET**:
Datasheet -> https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd18540q5b.pdf?ts=1644815881888&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Primary loss in low side FET is conduction loss given by:
[image]

Rdson = 3 @Vgs = 6V and b/w 25C-120C
= 8^2 * 3 * (1 -5/24) = **0.152W**
[image]

50*0.152 = **7.6C rise**

Based on these calculations it would seem to me that this design should be fine to drive 8A but i would like to see if you would agree. Thanks!

Comment: With what voltage do you switch MOSFETs? Make sure you don't exceed maximum Vgs (if you switch it with 24V, it sounds shifty, your high side mosfet has max Vgs of 20V)

Comment: vgs= 5v for high side and 6V for low side

Comment: Iout in those equations is Ioutrms =/ 8A, Vgsth is not exactly 2V (For FDD8647L), it differs. Qgd should be taken from Gate charge graph for your case (Drive,VDD etc). These values will have slight variations, If you have enough margin in selection of MOSFET you are fine. Otherwise you will be in trouble. 40 ⁰C/W is 1000milx1000mil board which is too much for specific boards. actual value will depend on your layout. Take 60-70⁰C/W. There are other losses also associated with your design. What is the switching frequency planned for design?

Comment: Switching frequency set up to be 0.691 Mhz